# Kernel Has Died - ipython

Tags: kernel, ipython, python-3.3, jupyter-notebook

I m getting aquainted with ipython and now i become a strange error: Kernel Has Died 
can anyone suggest a simple workflow to overtake this problem?

```
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-dc484a8e-c822-46b1-bc6d-a1e019a67258.json
[NotebookApp] Kernel dc484a8e-c822-46b1-bc6d-a1e019a67258 failed to respond to heartbeat
```

I become also:

```
"The kernel has died, would you like to restart it? If you do not restart the kernel, you will be able to save the notebook, but running code will not work until the notebook is reopened."
```

This problem occurs always when i try to run the instruction:

```
pieces = {'G-C': Cond.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-M': M.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-M+A': MA.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-M+T': MT.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-L': L.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-L+A': MA.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-L+T': LT.ix[:, [1]]
          }
```

Comment: You should give more details. Which version of IPython ? which os ? are you doing something specific ...etc

Comment: i' m using IPython3 and ubuntu 13.04.
i want to concat columns from several tables.

Comment: this is the instruction that doesn t work:

{pieces = {'G-C': Cond.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-M': M.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-M+A': MA.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-M+T': MT.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-L': L.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-L+A': MA.ix[:, [1]],
          'G-L+T': LT.ix[:, [1]]
          }}

Comment: Can you find out which of the data objects (`Cond.`, `M`, etc..) is causing the crash? Try to execute each of the `.ix` statements in a single cell of the notebook.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. My problem was solved by the following steps-

- Go to Conda terminal and close the running kernel( by prssing Ctrl+c)
- next type

  ```
  pip install ipyparallel
  ```

  this will re-intstall ipyparallel
- then restart the jupyter-notebook

Comment: My problem was that other jupiter notebook was using already the memory, so it was running out of memory. If you are using tensorflow please check that you didn't created already a graph in background.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens reliably on the same instruction, then the instruction is crashing the kernel, and your are just warned about that. There is just no way to determine wether the kernel crashed, or the network connexion with it dropped. Try to reproduce on a pure python interpreter, and to have a full minimal reproductible example, and we could decide if there is a bug to report and where.