# Using command line in Jupyter Notebook not executing commands in virtual environment

Tags: python, command-line, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I need to use the command line in Jupyter Notebook in a virtual environment, but the commands don't execute in the environment itself. I'm using Anaconda Navigator to open Jupyter Notebook. For background, I use a Mac.

Whenever I do something like `! pip install xyz`, it installs the package in the Anaconda directory for libraries (see the image). I made sure that the kernel is in the environment, so that's not the problem.

What's interesting is that if I try to import a package, I can only import packages from the environment itself, not the Anaconda libraries. In other words, installing packages doesn't occur in the environment, but importing packages does.

Image that shows the pip install:
[image: Image that shows the pip install]

This wouldn't matter that much because I could download packages in the Terminal itself, but I also need to do things like in the image below in my virtual environment, which is not possible to do in the Terminal (or is it?).

Example of what I need to do:
[image: Example of what I need to do]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: That error is fixed. However, I'm getting an error if I try to use a Python command:

[image: image of error].

The first line just defines the file path for the script (the last item in the list is a .py file). I tried doing "%%python" followed by the command, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: A couple things. Most importantly, for `pip` and `conda` you want to use the modern magics added to insure that they function in the environment that is backing the actual notebook. In your example, it would be `% pip install opencv-python`; see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information on the modern magic commands. Use of the exclamation point in conjunction with those is outdated for the reason you are encountering. A lot of time it would lead to environment issues by running somewhere else. ...

Comment: <continued> I think that should cover the concern in the title of your post? (By the way it should be `%pip install` WITHOUT A SPACE. Sorry for typo.) I'll add that because of automagics being enabled by default in most modern Jupyter, you are better off using no symbol, as opposed to the exclamation point because with no symbol, the automagics will handle it behind the scenes. However, for being clear to you & others explicit use of the magic symbol is best. Point #2: I think I can answer your "(or is it?)" question, too. I'm not a 100% sure I get what you are asking. ...

Comment: <continued> Besides `os.name` those comands in your second image are command line commands and so you can run the equivalents in the terminal by removing the exclamation point and converting the variables to shell-based variables. Those commands are agnostic of your environment as they use shell commands. Alternatively, you can run IPython in the terminal separate from Jupyter so that command could work as written. But maybe I'm missing the point? Presumably, though you picked Jupyter to do this because you get the literate computing aspect. You should be able to sort this out & use Jupyter.

Comment: @Wayne thank you so much! The magic commands work. Yeah, I'm not really familiar with the Terminal so I wasn't sure how to use those commands in the Terminal. But thanks for your help and insight!

Comment: Wait @Wayne could you check my edit on the post? I'm getting an error when I try to use magic with a python command.

Comment: There's no `%python` magic command. For running Python from inside a notebook use `%run` followed by the path and name of the script, including the `.py` extension. See about it [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run). You can run it in the namespace of the notebook by adding `-i` flag. That is nice for defining variables in the notebook. `%run` also works with IPython scripts so you can use magic commands, like `%store`& call shell commands with `!` in the script; be sure to use the `.ipy` extension for the script name. It helps speed up development.

Comment: @Wayne I'm getting an error when I try to do that: https://ibb.co/tzj4sXv. The first line defines the file path (the last item is a .py file), but it says the file can't be found. I also tried to just put the entire file path in the %run command, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I am on Mac by the way

Comment: Start smaller. Run `pwd` in your notebook. Make a `print('hello world')` script there and run it with just the script name. Then try the full path hardcoded in your notebook. Then try using your `path.join` approach. If all that works, move a copy of your script to there and try that process. Don't worry if your current working directory doesn't have all the stuff your script needs. You are just trying to troubleshoot the file not being found. If you find your working directory needs to be somewhere else, use `%cd` in the notebook to change the working directory.

Comment: Ok, I just used %cd to get to the directory with the script, and it appears that the file is now found. However, the kernel just dies when I use %run script ... That is a different problem though. It doesn't just happen once either; I've tried multiple times and get the same message.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502894/kernel-has-died-ipython. 

The comment to the first answer says "My problem was that other jupiter notebook was using already the memory, so it was running out of memory. If you are using tensorflow please check that you didn't created already a graph in background."

I am not sure what a "graph in background" is, but I am using TensorFlow. If, by any chance, you are familiar with using Tensorflow in Jupyter Notebook, do you have any idea what's going on? If not, that's completely ok, and I'll make a separate question for it.

Comment: I am thinking it's something to do with the fact that I have TensorFlow installed in two libraries (because when I was doing !pip install before it installed in Anaconda, not my virtual environment).

Comment: Additionally, the script doesn't actually use Tensorflow, it just checks if everything has installed. You can find it here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder_tf2_test.py

Comment: A separate question would be more appropriate. It sounds like a memory issue. I think the suggestion to make sure you don't have a graph in the background is just a tip on memory management. It probably commonly happens that people working out code make a graph that isn't quite what they want and they don't realize it's still in the the namespace and then hit the memory limit sooner than they should if all things were a clean slate.